# My html and css are not linking ( i have searched everything and i cant solve this)

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I recently started learning HTML and CSS. I've been trying to link my css for hours. I've searched more than 10 forums but nothing seems to be solving my issue. Ive tried to change the order of the [href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"], I've tried using other browsers, I've tried to clean my cache and obviously my html and my css are in the same folder.

Here is a screenshot of my html:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRYNU.png
Here is a screenshot of my css:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5fvP.png
Here is the live preview of my html:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP9LJ.png

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you may be wondering, note that your question is not getting downvoted because the question is dumb or anything like that, but likely because you're posting _links_ of _images_ of code instead of simply posting the actual code in the question, and because your title has the long irrelevant part in the parentheses. Since you're asking us we already know that you need help solving your issue: there is no need to say that in the title, it doesn't describe your issue in any way. Please refer to the "How to ask" page when asking your next question.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'll keep that in mind, i thought it would be easier for the eye to post screenshots

Comment: Please read this: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your CSS it's wrong, try this.

```
a { color: red; text-decoration:none }
```

It's not necessary a `style` in a `.css` file

Comment: Oh god bless you dude. Can't believe that was the issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yah, you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

In your css:

Don't say `a{style="..."}`, you use `style="..."`in your HTML-tags.

Correct way

```
a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

or

```
a{color:red;text-decoration:none;}
```

if you want to keep it in one line.

I don't think there is another mistake, the only thing I can come up with is that your CSS file is not in the same directory as your HTML file. If you want to have it in a different location, you have to put the path in your `href`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the css file located in the same folder as the html file?

You have to remove the *style="* part and the *"* near the end of line 1 in your css file. It breaks the stylesheet and your styles are not apllied because of this.

Greetings, Mario.

Answer (score 0):

you can add ?=1 in front of your stylesheet.css?=1. It should resolve your issue

Comment: my question has already been answered, thank you for your advice